# How to open iBook (in-app)

Tags: ibooks

I want to open an iBook file in one of my iPhone application without launching third party apps. I have gone through with many articles and all of those suggest use of UIDocumentInterectionController class.

When I tried this in demo app, it launches the iBooks application. But I have to open it with in my application itself without launching any supporting or third party app.

How can we achieve this functionality? Please help me with some code snippet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.